# Python regex outputting multiple matches

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, regex-group

I have the following example text:

```
60CC
60 cc
60cc2
60CC(2)
```

and the following regex to match these instances:

```
(60\s?(cc)(\w|\(.\)){0,5})
```

however my output is as follows for the first match:

```
['60CC', 'CC', None]
```

([Demo of the sample regex & data](https://pythex.org/?regex=(60%5Cs%3F(cc)(%5Cw%7C%5C(.%5C))%7B0%2C5%7D)&test_string=60CC%0A60%20cc%0A60cc2%0A60CC(2)&ignorecase=1&multiline=0&dotall=0&verbose=0).)

how do I limit the output to just the first item?

I am using Python Regex.
the snippet of my python code is:

```
re.findall("(60\s?(cc)(\w|\(.\)){0,5})", text, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
```

Comment: Use `match.group()`

Comment: lets start with clarifications. What exactly do you need? if you want the first one, why just not use "60CC" as regex?

Comment: Note that when you repeat the capturing group, the value of the third group for this string `60CC(2)(3)(4)` would be `(4)` and not `(2)(3)(4)`

Comment: You are getting `None` because of `{0,...}` which allows an empty string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> how do I limit the output to just #1 ?

You can just ignore the irrelevant groups from your findall/finditer results.

Alternatively, use *non-capturing* groups for the bits you don't care about: [just add `?:` after the leading parenthesis](https://pythex.org/?regex=(60%5Cs%3F(%3F%3Acc)(%3F%3A%5Cw%7C%5C(.%5C))%7B0%2C5%7D)&test_string=60CC%0A60%20cc%0A60cc2%0A60CC(2)&ignorecase=1&multiline=0&dotall=0&verbose=0), this way you can still use grouping features (e.g. alternation) without the group being captured (split out) in the result.

Comment: thank you this does the trick! - I have used the non-capturing groups method